# Group array of objects by key then count condition on that group

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to group by `keyword` and then see how many objects on that group have `page: 1`, then add a property that counts that on each group, e.g. `onPage1: 3`.

I have come up with this solution, using `new Map()` to group and then mapping over those results,

The problem with my approach is that if a group does not have a `page: 2` it will not reset the counter

```js
const data = [
  { keyword: 'hello', page: 1},
  { keyword: 'hello', page: 2},
  { keyword: 'hello', page: 2},
  // Keyword hello obj should have onPage1: 1
  { keyword: 'bye', page: 1},
  { keyword: 'bye', page: 1},
  { keyword: 'bye', page: 1},
  // Keyword bye obj should have onPage1: 3
  { keyword: 'foo', page: 1},
  { keyword: 'foo', page: 1},
  { keyword: 'foo', page: 1},
  { keyword: 'foo', page: 2}
  // Keyword foo obj should have onPage1: 3
]

const mapper = new Map()
let counter = 1
for (const { page, keyword } of data) {
  if (page === 1) {
    mapper.set(keyword, counter++)
  } else {
    counter = 1
  }
}

const res = data.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  onPage1: mapper.has(obj.keyword) && mapper.get(obj.keyword) 
}))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Expected output

```
[
  {
    "keyword": "hello",
    "page": 1,
    "onPage1": 1
  },
  {
    "keyword": "hello",
    "page": 2,
    "onPage1": 1
  },
  {
    "keyword": "hello",
    "page": 2,
    "onPage1": 1
  },
  {
    "keyword": "bye",
    "page": 1,
    "onPage1": 3
  },
  {
    "keyword": "bye",
    "page": 1,
    "onPage1": 3
  },
  {
    "keyword": "bye",
    "page": 1,
    "onPage1": 3
  },
  {
    "keyword": "foo",
    "page": 1,
    "onPage1": 3
  },
  {
    "keyword": "foo",
    "page": 1,
    "onPage1": 3
  },
  {
    "keyword": "foo",
    "page": 1,
    "onPage1": 3
  },
  {
    "keyword": "foo",
    "page": 2,
    "onPage1": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: can you add your expected result? (is it the output of your snippet?)

Comment: I will add the error and the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `total` obj to store the count and map() the total with the data to get the result.

```js
const data = [ { keyword: "hello", page: 1 }, { keyword: "hello", page: 2 }, { keyword: "hello", page: 2 }, { keyword: "bye", page: 1 }, { keyword: "bye", page: 1 }, { keyword: "bye", page: 2 }, { keyword: "foo", page: 1 }, { keyword: "foo", page: 1 }, { keyword: "foo", page: 1 }, { keyword: "foo", page: 2 }, ];

const total = data.reduce((acc, b) => {
  if (b.page === 1) {
    acc[b.keyword] ? (acc[b.keyword] += 1) : (acc[b.keyword] = 1);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const o = data.map(el => {
  el.onPage1 = total[el.keyword] || 0;
  return el;
});

console.log(o);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works really well too, in my case `page 1` will always exists, so it was fine without `|| 0` but nice catch. I wonder if this approach is preferable to the `new Map()`

Comment: @Álvaro, It is almost the same as using `new Map()`, but in your case `{}` is good enough. People use Map() because sometimes they need some other operation such as changing a Map object to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than keeping a global `counter`, you can update the count of each key based on the current value at that key. If the key hasn't been set yet, you can default it using `|| 0`:

```js
const data = [ { keyword: 'hello', page: 1}, { keyword: 'hello', page: 2}, { keyword: 'hello', page: 2}, { keyword: 'bye', page: 1}, { keyword: 'bye', page: 1}, { keyword: 'bye', page: 2}, { keyword: 'foo', page: 1}, { keyword: 'foo', page: 1}, { keyword: 'foo', page: 1}, { keyword: 'foo', page: 2} ];

const mapper = new Map();
for (const { page, keyword } of data) {
  if (page === 1) {
    const currentCount = mapper.get(keyword) || 0; // grab current count at the keyword, then update it on next line
    mapper.set(keyword, currentCount+1);
  }
}

const res = data.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  onPage1: mapper.get(obj.keyword) || 0 
}))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can updated the mapper to use reduce if you wish:

```
const mapper = data.reduce(
  (acc, {keyword, page}) => 
    page === 1 ? acc.set(keyword, (acc.get(keyword) ?? 0) + 1) : acc,
  new Map
);
```

```js
const data = [ { keyword: 'hello', page: 1}, { keyword: 'hello', page: 2}, { keyword: 'hello', page: 2}, { keyword: 'bye', page: 1}, { keyword: 'bye', page: 1}, { keyword: 'bye', page: 2}, { keyword: 'foo', page: 1}, { keyword: 'foo', page: 1}, { keyword: 'foo', page: 1}, { keyword: 'foo', page: 2} ];

const mapper = data.reduce(
  (acc, {keyword, page}) => 
    page === 1 ? acc.set(keyword, (acc.get(keyword) ?? 0) + 1) : acc,
  new Map
);

const res = data.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj, onPage1: mapper.get(obj.keyword) ?? 0 
}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks, do you think this should be done better with a reduce or with this approach?

Comment: Reduce also works, it’s just another way of creating the map. Some big names in the JS community are opposed to using reduce though as they feel as it unnecessarily complicates the code. I’ve added an example of using reduce also though (I’ve stepped away from my computer so it is currently untested)

Answer (score 0):

inorder to get such an object as result :

```
"keyword:hello-page:1": { count: 1 },
"keyword:hello-page:2": { count: 2 },
"keyword:bye-page:1": { count: 2 },
"keyword:bye-page:2": { count: 1 },
"keyword:foo-page:1": { count: 3 },
"keyword:foo-page:2": { count: 1 }
```

you can use following approche

```
const groupBy = data.reduce((per, curr) => {
if (!per[`keyword:${curr.keyword}-page:${curr.page}`]) {
    per[`keyword:${curr.keyword}-page:${curr.page}`] = { count: 1 }
}
else {
    per[`keyword:${curr.keyword}-page:${curr.page}`].count++
}
return per}, {})
```

and you can reach what count what u wish like that

```
console.log(groupBy['keyword:hello-page:1'].count)
```